# Backup Windows 7 settings before reinstall?

Tags: windows-7, backup

Is there any way to save these windows 7 settings: windows explorer settings, theme settings, file association, taskbar settings? Maybe some program that can do this?

I know Windows 7 has Windows Easy Transfer option, but it doesn't save this type of settings.

Comment: Windows Backup will save most of these settings.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the registry will definitely backup all of these settings. The downside is you cannot just write the registry back after the re-install you will have to be selective.